# How do I edit a CSS variable using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have these CSS variables to control the colors of my project so I can do theming.

```
html {
    --main-background-image: url(../images/starsBackground.jpg);
    --main-text-color: #4CAF50;
    --main-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    --beta-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
}
```

However no matter how I try to change the attribute(the two commented lines tried separately), the closest I get is returning not a valid attribute.

```
function loadTheme() {
    var htmlTag = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
    var yourSelect = document.getElementById( "themeSelect" );
    var selectedTheme = ( yourSelect.options[ yourSelect.selectedIndex ].value );
    // htmlTag[0].setAttribute('--main-text-color', '#FFCF40');
    // $("html").css("--main-text-color","#FFCF40");
}
```

[image: the error message]

Comment: https://www.broken-links.com/2014/08/28/css-variables-updating-custom-properties-javascript/

Comment: Yes, those CSS variables use a 'native' pre-processor (basically, they eventually get converted into the real property/attribute beforehand).  BTW, this feature is not widely supported by all browsers (only FF, from the article. I dunno about other browsers) - in any case, your syntax is incorrect if you want to manipulate them in JS.  You need to manipulate properties (not attributes, it seems) - so try `htmlTag[0].styles.setProperty('--main-text-color', '#FFCF40');`

Comment: I copied your answer in and now the error is that it can not set property of undefined. Could I bother you for a fiddle example?

Comment: Checkout my answer for widely-supported ways of doing something similar OR even better, checkout Brett's answer for how to solve your question (with limited browser support) http://stackoverflow.com/a/41371037/600486

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Turns out changing CSS variables is possible using the `el.style.cssText` property, or `el.style.setProperty` or `el.setAttribute` methods. In your code snippets `el.setAttribute` is incorrectly used, which is causing the error you encountered. Here's the correct way:

```
document.documentElement.style.cssText = "--main-background-color: red";
```

or

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--main-background-color", "green");
```

or

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "--main-background-color: green");
```

**Demo**

The following demo defines a background color using a CSS variable, then changes it using the JS snippet 2 seconds after loading.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.documentElement.style.cssText = "--main-background-color: red";
  }, 2000);
};
```

```css
html {
    --main-background-image: url(../images/starsBackground.jpg);
    --main-text-color: #4CAF50;
    --main-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    --beta-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--main-background-color);
}
```

This will only work in browsers supporting CSS variables obviously.

Comment: This will overwrite the existing inline styles.

Comment: yes you need to modify the prop like this:         **document.querySelector("html").style.setProperty('width', fixed.width + 'px')** however I can't get it to work

Comment: I'm guessing that `html.style.setProperty("--main-background-color", "green");` is the preferred way to do it. Using `setAttribute('style', ..)` will overwrite any other inline styles and the same goes for `style.cssText = ...`

Answer (score 37):

If you are using `:root`:

```
:root {
    --somevar: black;
}
```

It will be documentElement.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--somevar', 'green');
```

Answer (score 30):

### The native solution

The **standard methods** to get/set CSS3 variables are `.setProperty()` and `.getPropertyValue()`.

If your Variables are Globals (declared in `:root`), you can use the following, for getting and setting their values.

```
// setter
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myVariable', 'blue');
// getter
document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--myVariable');
```

**However the getter will only return the value of a var, if has been set, using `.setProperty()`**. 
If has been  set through CSS declaration, will return `undefined`.  Check it in this example:

```js
let c = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--myVariable');
alert('The value of --myVariable is : ' + (c?c:'undefined'));
```

```css
:root{ --myVariable : red; }
div{ background-color: var(--myVariable); }
```

```html
  <div>Red background set by --myVariable</div>
```

To avoid that unexpected behavior you have to make use of the `getComputedStyle()`method , before calling `.getPropertyValue()`.
The getter will then , look lik this :

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,null).getPropertyValue('--myVariable');
```

***In my opinion, accessing CSS variables should be more simple, fast, intuitive and natural...***

---

### My personal approach

I've implemented `CSSGlobalVariables` a tiny (<3kb) javascript module wich automatically detects and packs into an Object, all the active CSS global variables in a document, **for easier acces & manipulation**.

```
import {CSSGlobalVariables} from './css-global-variables.js';
let cssVar = new CSSGlobalVariables();
// set the CSS global --myColor value to "green"
cssVar.myColor = "green";
```

Any change applied to the Object properties, is translated automatically to the CSS variables, and viceversa.

**Available in** : https://github.com/colxi/css-global-variables

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use the standard way of setting arbitrary CSS properties: [**`setProperty`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty)

```js
document.body.style.setProperty('--background-color', 'blue');
```

```css
body {
  --background-color: red;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
```

Comment: for some reason I can't get this to work when the var is used in a transition like so:   **left: calc(10% - (var(--width) / 2));**

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who is struggling with it, if your CSS variable is a sentence you need to wrap it in qoutes.

```css
:root {
  --my-css-var: 'Hello Person!';
}

.selector:after {
    content: var(--my-css-var);
}
```

This does not work:

```js
let myVar = 'Hi Person! (doesnt work)';
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.setProperty('--my-css-var', myVar);
```

But this does:

```js
let myVar = 'Hi Person! (works)';
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.setProperty('--my-css-var', '"' + myVar + '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like below (without using class variables)

```js
function loadTheme() {
  var htmlTag = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  var yourSelect = document.getElementById("themeSelect");
  var selectedTheme = (yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value);
  console.log("selected theme: " + selectedTheme);

  // reset class names
  htmlTag.className = '';
  // add selected theme
  htmlTag.className = 'theme' + selectedTheme;
}
```

```css
.theme1 {
  color: blue;
}
.theme2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  test
</div>
<select id="themeSelect" onChange="loadTheme()">
  <option value="1">Theme 1</option>
  <option value="2">Theme 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Ced wait! are you saying that my answer does not address the OP's need to do theming?  - I am not sure I'd agree with you.   Just because I answer in a widely-supported ways (instead of using a limited-browser-support approach)  - please read: How To Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -> Answers can be "don't do this" but "try this instead".... **shrugs**

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to define classes in your CSS that contain the various theme styles (`.theme1 {...}`, `.theme2 {...}`, etc) and then change the class with JS based on the selected value.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: I didn't think about that. I'll give that a shot and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

The ::placeholder selector is not available in javascript, however a walk around this, would be to declare a css variable in your style sheet, this variable would be available to the DOM and can be manipulated using javascript.

Example.

```js
let root = document.querySelector(':root');
function setPlaceholderColor(){
root.style.setProperty('--placeholder', yellow);
}
```

```css
:root{
  --placeholder: red;
}

input::placeholder{
  color: var(--placeholder)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder ="Enter Name" onchange="setPlaceholderColor()" />
```

Comment: The code given error : Uncaught ReferenceError: yellow is not defined

Comment: need proper testing of code