# Can I change the variables of a scss file in angular 2

Tags: css, angular, sass, styles

I'm using right now angular 2 with a style in scss, but I need to get a data from a server to change a variable of the component style more exactly it's a percentage.[Here](https://codepen.io/kunalkamble/pen/XXbWwN) you can find the code scss and the html:

The variable that I want to modify it would be percentage:

`$configs: (
    chart-one: (
        svgSize: 200px,
        percentage: 32,
        strokeWidth: 1px,
        backgroundColor: #305556,
        foregroundColor: #79be9b,
        labelColor: #c6e8d7,
        labelFontSize: 2.5rem,
        duration: 3s,
        animationDelay: 1s
    )
);`

In the component of this circle, I want to get the data of a server and change the percentage of the variable of the scss file, I would like to know if that is possible? Or If you have an example it would be great

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741  the new css variables are for you? take note on the browser compatiblity

Answer (score 0):

No i do not think so you can instead it you can use some logic from your component to mixup with classed. e.g this percentage can be part of component and there you can change it over time same approach can be achieved with directive.