# Handle CSS change (color picked by user) on hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a PHP/HTML application in which the user selects the background color they want. It is saved in an ini file and it's used when the page is reloaded.

Now, users would like to do the same thing with the "hovered" color of the many different user actions elements. I have already added the `Hoverable` class to effectively able to style all those actions elements.

Now, I need to change the `.Hoverable:hover` `background-color`, but the following doesn't seem to work: `$(".Hoverable:hover").css("background-color, new_value);"`

Is there an easy and effective way to dynamically change a property value in the CSS of a hovered class?

Here is a simplified snippet to illustrate my problem.

```js
$("#textareaID").bind("input propertychange", function() {
  //console.log($("#textareaID").val());
  $("#body").attr("user_color", $("#textareaID").val());

  // I Need to change the .Hoverable:hover background-color, but the following doesn't work
  $(".Hoverable:hover").css("background-color", $("#textareaID").val());
});

// Line below makes the above triggers on load
$("#textareaID").trigger("input");
```

```css
body {
  font: 18px arial, sans-serif;
}

#textareaID,
.Tool,
.Link,
.Button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: all 0.4s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#textareaID {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Tool {
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
}

.Link {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.Button {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}

.Hoverable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Hoverable:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body" user_color="#ddddff">

  <!-- In my case, my color selection is not a textarea, I used it to make things simplier -->
  Color selected: <textarea id="textareaID">#ddddff</textarea>
  <br> User possible actions:
  <div class="Tool Hoverable">DIV</div>
  <br>
  <a class="Link Hoverable">LINK</a>
  <br>
  <button class="Button Hoverable">BUTTON</button>

</body>
```

Comment: try something like `$(".Hoverable").hover(function() {$(this).css("background-color", $("#textareaID").val())});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify by using CSS variable:

```js
$("#textareaID").on("input change", function() {
  $("#body").attr("user_color", $(this).val());
  
  $(":root").attr("style","--color-hover:"+$(this).val())
});

// Line below makes the above triggers on load
$("#textareaID").trigger("input");
```

```css
:root {
 --color-hover:#ffffff;
}

body {
  font: 18px arial, sans-serif;
}

#textareaID,
.Tool,
.Link,
.Button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: all 0.4s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#textareaID {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Tool {
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
}

.Link {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.Button {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}

.Hoverable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Hoverable:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  background-color:var(--color-hover);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body" user_color="#ddddff">

  <!-- In my case, my color selection is not a textarea, I used it to make things simplier -->
  Color selected: <textarea id="textareaID">#ddddff</textarea>
  <br> User possible actions:
  <div class="Tool Hoverable">DIV</div>
  <br>
  <a class="Link Hoverable">LINK</a>
  <br>
  <button class="Button Hoverable">BUTTON</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for that method, I really like it. Does the variable need to be defined on `:root`, or can we on `body` too ?

Comment: @TakitIsy yes you can have it on body ;) you can also have it only on the needed element ... but its scope will only be this element and their child ... so when using with :root your are sure you can use the variable with any element

Comment: @TakitIsy i advise to read more about them :) they are really useful and will help optimize a lot your code ;) https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

Comment: I'll do. And I'll use those. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I've got another little question. I am using the css variables now. In your code, above, `$(":root").attr("style","--color-hover:"+$(this).val())` erases all inside the style attribute. I need to use more than one variable. Is there an easy way to pick the variable to write to in the style `attr`, in jQuery ?

Comment: @TakitIsy check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41371125/8620333 it may help you ... there is a lot of ways by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go with an easy solution combinning `focusin`, `focusout` and `keyup` events:

```js
var val = ""
$("#textareaID").on("focusin focusout keyup", function() {
    val = $(this).val()
});
$(".Hoverable").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", val);
});
$(".Hoverable").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 18px arial, sans-serif;
}

#textareaID,
.Tool,
.Link,
.Button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: all 0.4s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#textareaID {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Tool {
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
}

.Link {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.Button {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}

.Hoverable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Hoverable:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body" user_color="#ddddff">

  <!-- In my case, my color selection is not a textarea, I used it to make things simplier -->
  Color selected (Write any color and test it): <textarea id="textareaID">red</textarea>
  
  <br /> User possible actions:
  <div class="Tool Hoverable">DIV</div>
  <br />
  <a class="Link Hoverable">LINK</a>
  <br />
  <button class="Button Hoverable">BUTTON</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. It's working nicely, but I prefer not to bind many functions in my code. I'm pretty sure some people will like it !