# How to get css variables value set in style sheet?

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I have this css:

```
body {
    --animation: terminal-bar;
    --size: 1.4;
}
```

how can I get value of `--animation` in JavaScript?

I've tried this:

```
getComputedStyle(document.body)['--animation'];
document.body.style.getPropertyValue('--animation');
```

they both don't work, I've found this in developer tools:

```
document.body.computedStyleMap().get('--animation')[0]
```

but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap) it's suppored only in Chrome.

Is there relatively Cross-Browser solution (it don't need to work in IE) where you can get value of css variable set in css style sheet?

Comment: also related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js

Comment: Would this work? `window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue("--animation");`

Comment: it's working fine for me : https://jsfiddle.net/z8v65qob/1/ [the solution from the duplicate]

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes duplicate works, I was searching the questions but didn't found that one.