# Change the CSS4 variables dynamically

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I have to handle multiple `primary` and other CSS4 variables for different companies. How can I handle this kind of use case? i.e. change the primary CSS4 variable color dynamically according to the company?

***Note:*** My use case here is I just need to update the `primary` variable without considering the html element. Then it affects all the places where `primary` has been used.

*.html*

```
 <ion-button color="primary" (click)="reservation()">Book Now</ion-button>
```

*variables.scss*

```
:root {
  /** primary **/
  --ion-color-primary: rgb(180, 151, 90);
}
```

The other company has this: But I need to set this dynamically.

```
  :root {
      /** primary **/
      --ion-color-primary: rgb(129 147 171);
    }
```

Can I use a service for that?

```
export class ThemeSwitcherService {

  constructor() { }


  setTheme(data: string): void {

    switch (data) {
      case "com1":
        primary:com1 color//how to do it here
        break;
      case "com2":
       primary:com2 color
        break;
      default:
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/css-variables-javascript/

Comment: it's not `CSS4`. technically there is no CSS4 there is only CSS3 and beyond https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css-levels

Comment: @Sergey My use case here is I just need to update the `primary` variable without considering the html element. Then it affects all the places where `primary` has been used.

Comment: Like this maybe? ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js

Comment: @LGSon Yes, that helped me a lot. I'll put an `Ionic/ angular` version of answer later. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the theme switcher I have used.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeSwitcherService {

  constructor(private domCtrl: DomController,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

  setTheme(data: string): void {

    switch (data) {
      case "com1":
        this.domCtrl.write(() => {
          this.document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ion-color-primary", "rgb(180, 151, 90)");
        });
        break;
      case "com2":
        this.domCtrl.write(() => {
          this.document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ion-color-primary", "rgb(129,147,171)");
        });
        break;
      default:
    }

  }
}
```

This helped me a lot : [Theme Switcher](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-theme-switcher-service-in-ionic-using-css4-variables/)