# How to apply font-size property based on the value of variable passed to css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply style to paragraph element based on the value of the variable passed from java script code.

Here is what I have tried

```js
var fontSize = 50;
```

```css
.wrapper {
    **width:320px;**
}
.wrapper > input {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: pink;
 **width:450px;**


}
.wrapper > p {
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color:white;
    font-weight: normal;
    **width:450px;**
}

 .wrapper > input:hover + #spandiv {
font-size : var(--fontSize); //I am not sure how to do this , I this value to be in pixel
background-color: grey;
display: block;
opacity: 1;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
color:white;
font-weight: normal;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input id="input1" type="text">
            <p id="spandiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</p> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want font-size property to pick up the value of variable. Hoe to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js

Comment: This is the whole point of why they invented `em` and `rem` which are relative units. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units

Comment: Hi 04FS, I went through the link how to setproperty to some pixel value ex: var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
html.setAttribute("style", "--main-background-color:"+data+"px");  my style is font-weight:var(--main-background-color);