# Finishing a css-animation before triggering a new one

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I am trying to create a moving image upon hovering and un-hovering. The animation should flow one way while the mouse is over the image, and the other way while the mouse leaves the image.

For this, I am currently using a css animation with an image sprite. The issue is that when the mouse moves over/leaves the image before the animation time (1 second) has passed, then the image spite will jump to the beginning of the next animation without finishing its previous animation.

I have tried various ways to tackle this but I simply cannot seem to make it work (yes, that's my current lack of skills). What would be a way to let the animations always finish before starting a new one?

http://jsfiddle.net/16jync0h/latest

**HTML**

```
<div id="navOpen"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navOpen {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/hv0L4vsL/css-sprites.png') no-repeat left/cover;
}

.navOpenPlay {
  animation: Play 1s steps(24) 1 forwards;
}

.navOpenPlayBack {
  animation: PlayBack 1s steps(24) 1 backwards;
}

@keyframes Play {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
}

@keyframes PlayBack {
  0% {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
}
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
 $("#navOpen").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("navOpenPlayBack").addClass("navOpenPlay");
 });
 $("#navOpen").mouseout(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("navOpenPlay").addClass("navOpenPlayBack");
 });
```

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to reverse your animation when leaving before finishing the animation, the animation can be linked with the css `:hover` selector:

```css
#navOpen{
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  /* reused the css-sprites because of laziness... */
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/hv0L4vsL/css-sprites.png') no-repeat left/cover; 
  transition: transform 2s;
}

#navOpen:hover{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navOpen"></div>
```

However, if you really want to finish the whole animation before reversing, it's a bit more verbose. The main reason is that you have to verify everytime when an animation ended, if it's still in the correct *state*. Whereby I'm referring to *state* as if the user is hovering over your `#navbar` and it's having the class `navOpenPlay` or `navOpenPlayBack` assigned.

```js
// Javascript accessor to use "onanimationend"
let nav = document.getElementById("navOpen")
// First of all, we need to keep track if an animation is running or not. 
// This helps us, to prevent interruption of an animation through adding/removing css classes before the animation finished.
// We stock this information in the variable `navIsReady`.
let navIsReady = true

// Define a function to change the state. 
// If play === true, we add animation for onMouseOver by adding the corresponding css classes
function changeState(play) {
  // Verify if another animation is currently running
  if (navIsReady === true) {
    navIsReady = false // indicate that an animation is running
    if (play) { // previously called on mouseOver
      $(nav).removeClass("navOpenPlayBack").addClass("navOpenPlay")
    } else { // previously called on mouseOut
      $(nav).removeClass("navOpenPlay").addClass("navOpenPlayBack")
    }
  }
}

// Define a callback when an animation ends. 
// The callback checks that the object is in the right state after finishing the animation
nav.onanimationend = function(event) {
  navIsReady = true // allow animations again
  // Check if the navigation is in the correct state after finishing the animation 
  if ($(nav).is(':hover') && (!$(nav).hasClass("navOpenPlay"))) {
    // False state. Change the state through a call
    changeState(true)
  } else if (!$(nav).is(':hover') && (!$(nav).hasClass("navOpenPlayBack"))) {
    // False state. Change the state through a call
    changeState(false)
  }
};

// Hook MouseOver and MouseOut events
$(nav).mouseover(function() {
  changeState(true)
});
$(nav).mouseout(function() {
  changeState(false)
});
```

```css
#navOpen {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/hv0L4vsL/css-sprites.png') no-repeat left/cover;
}

.navOpenPlay {
  animation: Play 1s steps(24) 1 forwards;
}

.navOpenPlayBack {
  animation: PlayBack 1s steps(24) 1 backwards;
}

@keyframes Play {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
}

@keyframes PlayBack {
  0% {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navOpen"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this well-explained answer. I was looking into your first solution, as reverting the animation mid-way seems a good option as well. I am going to also use this effect for other images, which are not simply rotatable, so therefore I really need the image-sprites way of doing it (with 'steps' & 'background-position'). However, when unhovered the total amount of steps is assigned to the reduced with of the sprite, resulting in this:
 
https://jsfiddle.net/jipasveld/oa8xg267/5/  would there be a fix for this?

Comment: That's right. I can't think of a pure css solution that knows how many steps it should __revert__ on unhovering. But it should be possible using javascript.

Comment: I would try to define a [css variable](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) that defines the number of steps used for the animation. Then you might be able to [update this variable through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js) onMouseEnter/Leave with the number of steps it should use. Something like `(totalSpriteWidth - currentOffset) / singleSpriteWidth`.
But it sounds rather complicated to me and maybe there's an easier solution.

Comment: Or you could do the animation simple in javascript and change the backgroundPosition 24 times :)

Comment: So, here you go. A small snippet that shows [how to do the sprite animation in javascript](https://codepen.io/ug27/pen/zYvEoWZ). However, this isn't a version that would scale well. So you'd have to adapt quite a bite to handle multiple animations in a reasonable way...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @NoSkill, you can use the [`onanimationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend) event to listen for when the animation is complete and add your custom logic there.

You can then combine this with a queue to keep track of what is currently animating and what to animate next.

See example:

```js
let isAnimating = false;
const animationQueue = [];

function queueAnimation(cssClass) {
  animationQueue.push(cssClass);
  if (!isAnimating) {
    triggerAnimation();
  }
}

function triggerAnimation() {
  const cssClass = animationQueue.shift();
  if (cssClass) {
    $("#navOpen").attr('class', '').addClass(cssClass);
    isAnimating = true;
  }
}

$("#navOpen").mouseover(function() {
  queueAnimation('navOpenPlay');
});
$("#navOpen").mouseout(function() {
  queueAnimation('navOpenPlayBack');
});
$("#navOpen").on("animationend", function() {
  isAnimating = false;
  triggerAnimation();
});
```

```css
#navOpen {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/hv0L4vsL/css-sprites.png') no-repeat left/cover;
}

.navOpenPlay {
  animation: Play 1s steps(24) 1 forwards;
}

.navOpenPlayBack {
  animation: PlayBack 1s steps(24) 1 backwards;
}

@keyframes Play {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
}

@keyframes PlayBack {
  0% {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navOpen"></div>
```