# Change CSS variable through user input

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there a way to change a CSS variable based on user input?

For instance, I would like to be able to type either a hex code or color name into an input textbox, and have the CSS change reflected live.

Got the idea from a tutorial on CSS variables and thought it might be a fun way to practice.

I know how to make an input box, but I have no idea how to use the entered data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I edit a CSS variable using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use setProperty('--my-css-var', value)

```js
const color = document.querySelector('#color');
color.addEventListener('input', e => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', color.value)
})
```

```css
h1 {
   color: var(--color, blue)
}
```

```html
<input id="color" />
<h1>Color me :)</h1>

<p>Try #F0F, orange, tomato, olive,...</p>
```