# Changing strokeStyle value from input

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm creating simple drawing app with vanilla Javascript. My current issue is I'm trying to change strokeStyle value from input but just can't figure out how to do that. I tried to do that through CSS root value but if there's another simple way to do it I'm open to try it.

```
<div class="optioninputs">
   <label for="brushcolor"></label>
   <input id="brushcolor" type="color" name="brushcolor" value="#000000">
</div>
```

Here is my HTML code and that input value I'm trying to change.

```
:root {
   --brushcolor: #000000;
}
```

CSS root value.

```
// Get brushcolor root value
const brushElement = document.getElementById('brushcolor');
const brushColor = getComputedStyle(brushElement). getPropertyValue('--brushcolor');

context.strokeStyle = brushColor;
```

There's problem itself. That gets correct root value from CSS but how to change that root value from Javascript?

EDIT:

```
brushElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--brushcolor', e.target.value);
});
```

I've tried this one but it wasn't working

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js) might help

Comment: I checked that thread before but didn't found solution from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working fine. Maybe you wanted the "input" event instead of "change"?

The `input` event will change it immediately 
The `change` event will only change it after you click outside the color picker

If you want to use this color value you can simply assign it to a variable

```
context.strokeStyle = e.target.value;
```

```js
document.getElementById('brushcolor').addEventListener('change', e => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--brushcolor', e.target.value);
});
document.getElementById('brushcolor2').addEventListener('input', e => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--brushcolor', e.target.value);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --brushcolor: #000000;
}

.variablebackground {
  background-color: var(--brushcolor);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="variablebackground"></div>
  <div class="optioninputs">
    <label for="brushcolor">change eventlistener</label>
    <input id="brushcolor" type="color" name="brushcolor" value="#000000">
    <br />
    <label for="brushcolor2">input eventlistener</label>
    <input id="brushcolor2" type="color" name="brushcolor2" value="#000000">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I can change elements value from color picker but problem is I need to change that context.strokeStyle value which isn't element itself if I'm right.

Comment: you could simply use `context.strokeStyle = e.target.value` in the event function

Comment: That works, thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for last two days

Comment: @Arttu if the answer solves your problem and you do not need any additional help, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!