# How can I use data in css with Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to design a button component with Vue.

When I get main props, how can I get in css --mainColor variable without setting inline-style? thanks.

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";

    export default Vue.extend({
    name: "Button",
    props: {
        text: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        },
        main: {
            type: String,
            default: "#10b981"
        }
    }
});
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.btn {
    --mainColor: #10b981;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid var(--mainColor);
    color: var(--mainColor);
    &:hover {
        background-color: var(--mainColor);
        color: #fff;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You could use your created hook and set it with something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172679/5508690)

Comment: @StevenB. It works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that's possible. But you can run conditional logic in sass, like their official example:

```
$light-background: #f2ece4;
$light-text: #036;
$dark-background: #6b717f;
$dark-text: #d2e1dd;

@mixin theme-colors($light-theme: true) {
  @if $light-theme {
    background-color: $light-background;
    color: $light-text;
  } @else {
    background-color: $dark-background;
    color: $dark-text;
  }
}

.banner {
  @include theme-colors($light-theme: true);
  body.dark & {
    @include theme-colors($light-theme: false);
  }
}
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

Comment: Thanks for your answer first, but it seems complex to me. I prefer using methods of setProperty when mounted.

Answer (score 0):

This is super easy if using Vue3:

```
<template>
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      h1Color: "red",
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style>
h1 {
  color: v-bind(h1Color);
}
</style>
```

For a more extensive guide - [here](https://learnvue.co/2021/05/how-to-use-vue-css-variables-reactive-styles-rfc/#how-can-we-use-sfc-styles)

If using Vue2 I would suggest using the same approach as in Steven B's answer, here the [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js/47172679#47172679)