# How to change hover color using onclick button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to switch multiple colors in a page like theme change. I successfully changed text color, text background color, shapes color, button color etc. But I also want to change hover color.

This is the html code:-

```
 <ul class="color-changer">
        <li><a href="#" id="red">RED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="green">GREEN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="blue">BLUE</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This code works:-

```
<script>
    $('#red').click(function () {
        $('.sidebar button').css({
            'background-color': 'red'
        });
        $('.text-color').css({
            'background-color': 'red'
        });
        $('.shape-left').css({
            'background-color': 'red'
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this dont work:-

```
<script>
    $('#red').click(function () {
        $('.sidebar button:hover').css({
            'background-color': 'red'
        });
       
    });
</script>
```

Please help me. I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: look at [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), that may be a better way to do this

Comment: I am new. Please help me to understand it.

Comment: Instead of changing css properties, you might want to create different css classes for different themes and change the class names. Or even better as already mentioned, look into using css variables.

Comment: You can combine the documentation on CSS variables given above with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41371037/7310570.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using CSS variables changed through Javascript. I'll recommend you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to better understand what is happening here.

```js
let themes = {
  red: {
    '--sidebar-bg': '#FFAEBE',
    '--sidebar-a-color': '#88001B',
    '--sidebar-a-hover-color': '#FF0033',
  },
  green: {
    '--sidebar-bg': '#BBFFAE',
    '--sidebar-a-color': '#148800',
    '--sidebar-a-hover-color': '#3DFF00',
  },
  blue: {
    '--sidebar-bg': '#AEEFFF',
    '--sidebar-a-color': '#006E88',
    '--sidebar-a-hover-color': '#00CEFF',
  },
};

$('.color-changer').on('click', 'a', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let theme = $(e.target).data('theme');
  setSidebarTheme(theme);
});

function setSidebarTheme(theme) {
  let sidebar = $('#sidebar')[0]; // Get the raw Element, not jQuery
  for(let [prop, value] of Object.entries(themes[theme])) {
    // set value to the CSS variable
    sidebar.style.setProperty(prop, value);
  }
}

// initial theme
setSidebarTheme('blue');
```

```css
#sidebar { padding: 20px; }

#sidebar {
  background: var(--sidebar-bg);
}

#sidebar a {
  color: var(--sidebar-a-color);
}

#sidebar a:hover {
  color: var(--sidebar-a-hover-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar">
  <ul class="color-changer">
    <li><a href="#" data-theme="red">RED</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-theme="green">GREEN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-theme="blue">BLUE</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #red:hover
    {
    background-color:"color"
    }
```

For all id(red,green,blue) you can do this in css

Comment: This changes the hover color of that specific button only. Not for example for the sidebar button OP is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

using variable and [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) you could do the job: (you cant modify css style with :hover)

```js
var red = {'background-color': 'red'};
var redhover = {'background-color': 'yellow'};
$('#red').click(function() {
  $('.sidebar button').css(red);
  $('.text-color').css(red);
  $('.shape-left').css(red);
  redhover = {'background-color': 'pink'};
});


$(".sidebar button").hover(function() {
    $(this).css(redhover);
  },function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="color-changer">
  <li><a href="#" id="red">RED</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="green">GREEN</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="blue">BLUE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This only applies to if you want the hover color of this particular button to change. Not for any other elements on the page, you want to change the theme of.

Comment: @Kielstra negative that changes following the selector you set

Comment: ah yes, you're right about that. I was reading it that way because of the `#red` selector I guess.

Comment: anyways there are 2 solutions only or you do by js or you do by CSS like the other solution